# Hue/Color Overlay Transition Html/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, overlay

Below is a chunk of my code. Suppose I want the header background image to change between colors on a timer. Ex: purple, to blue, to green, to red, back to purple and repeat. I don't want to pull new image files into the code. I just want to implement something over the current image that changes the hue. How would I go about this? I assume I will need javascript for the timer.

```css
    @font-face {
    font-family: modernline;
    src: url("fonts/modernline.otf");
}

header {
    background-image: url("https://imgur.com/oSnFoHy");
    font-family: 'modernline', 'Lucida Sans';
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-shadow: 5px 1px 2.5px rgb(196, 187, 187);
}

.navigation ul{
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular';
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.navigation ul li {
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: whitesmoke;
    text-decoration-thickness: 2%;
    }

.navigation ul li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: goldenrod;
    text-decoration-color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
       <header>
    <h1>My Name</h1>
        <section class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#aboutMe">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#aboutWork">Work</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#aboutResume">Resume</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#aboutContat">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one method of going about what you want with some predefined colors:

```js
const header = document.getElementById('header')
const colorChanger = setInterval(() => {

 const colors = ['blue','red','cyan']
  colors.forEach(color => header.classList.remove(color))
  header.classList.add(colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)])

},1000)
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: modernline;
    src: url("fonts/modernline.otf");
}

header {
        background-image: url("https://www.dictionary.com/e/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/green_shades4-790x310.jpg");
    font-family: 'modernline', ;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-shadow: 5px 1px 2.5px rgb(196, 187, 187);
}
.blue{
        background-blend-mode: screen;
    background-color: blue;

}
.red{
        background-blend-mode: screen;
    background-color: red;

}
.green{
         background-blend-mode: screen;
    background-color: green;

}
.navigation ul{
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular';
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.navigation ul li {
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: whitesmoke;
    text-decoration-thickness: 2%;
    }

.navigation ul li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: goldenrod;
    text-decoration-color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
<h1 >My Name</h1>
    <section class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#aboutMe">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#aboutWork">Work</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#aboutResume">Resume</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#aboutContat">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</header>
```

Edit: fixed it so it does it to the hue.

Comment: This answer does not A) alter any images and B) sets background-image instead of manipulating the hue.

Comment: Sorry I fixed it.